# Determine if category is new in Magento

Tags: magento

I have an event hook in my `config.xml` which fires after a category has ***added or edited*** been via the administration area:

```
    <events>

        <catalog_category_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_savecategoryrules>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCategoryRules</method>
                </mymodule_savecategoryrules>
            </observers>
        </catalog_category_save_commit_after> 

    </events>
```

Here is a snippet from my observer:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer 
{

    public function saveCategoryRules($observer) 
    {

        $event      = $observer->getEvent();
        $category   = $event->getCategory();
        $categoryId = $category->getId();

        var_dump($categoryId); // Returns a category ID if edited or the new ID if added

    }
 }
```

I need to know if the category is new, is there an alternative hook or other method to determine this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer my own question just in case anybody else finds this useful. Add a new event listener in `config.xml` with the hook `catalog_category_prepare_save`:

```
        <catalog_category_prepare_save>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_savecategory>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCategory</method>
                </mymodule_savecategory>
            </observers>
        </catalog_category_prepare_save>
```

And my observer method:

```
public function saveCategory($observer) 
{

    $event      = $observer->getEvent();
    $category   = $event->getCategory();

    if (!$category->getId()) {
        echo 'No ID - must be new';
    } else {
        echo $category->getId();
    }

}
```

Comment: Then how can I get new Category ID using same observer event.

Comment: with catalog_category_save_after